# Squid redirect all requests to same page

Tags: redirect, proxy, squid

I am new to Squid and I want to redirect all requests to one static page. I have made a research but have not found anything about it.

Could someone share how to configure Squid like that?

It should look like:

1. You use my proxy
2. You go to google.com
3. You get redirected to www.mysite.com

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that.

Just use default squid settings and edit ACCESS_DENIED error file to get a static message, completely meets my requirements.